# Unable to fetch alert rules. Is the Prometheus data source properly configured?

Tags: amazon-web-services, prometheus-alertmanager, grafana-loki

Failed to load the data source configuration for Prometheus. Unable to fetch alert rules. Is the Prometheus  data source properly configured?

Prometheus data source is working fine.
I am use AWS Grafana Manage Service.[image]
[image]

This Alert rules issues happened, after Grafana alerting is On.

Comment: You could hav added more details in this question for others to comment. Also what you have tried so far

Comment: I enable grafana alerting in AWS Grafana. Because Alerting(legacy) shown in AWS Grafana.